# Custom ActionBar title in Android not centering?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a custom layout for my ActionBar.  It's a LinearLayout with a single TextView with today's date.  The TextView is perfectly centered on 4.0+ devices, and even on a 3.0 emulator.  But it is slightly off-center in the 3.2 emulator:

[image: screenshot]

I do this in my main Activity:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom);
dateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
```

and here is the the actionbar_custom.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks as though the overflow button is taking up layout space and might be the reason the date is not centering.  But on my 4.0+ devices, the overflow icon is present but the date is perfectly centered, so I am confused.

UPDATE:

I think I found the source of the problem.  I'm using a work-around in my Application class to force the overflow button to appear on devices that have a menu key:

```
try 
{
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if(menuKeyField != null) 
    {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Ignore
}
```

It seems like this is forcing the overflow icon to appear in its own layout.

Is there a way to place my TextView inside the overall parent layout of the ActionBar on these devices?  That way I could center the TextView within that.

Comment: @Raghunandan In the emulator with "hardware keys" enabled (like my 3.0 emulator), the overflow icon is not present, but the text is centered.

Comment: android versions 3.X are less than 0.1% according to the dashboards. Don't waste your time https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net

Comment: @LordRaydenMK I'm really tempted to because customizing the ActionBar layouts for 3.x devices is nothing short of a nightmare :)

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use relative layout and add centerInParent = "true" to your textview.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I tried that and it's still in the same position.  Do you have any other ideas?